# How can we get pass data from child to parent in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I need to get pass data from Range to Slide onChange, Range is the child inside the slider component.

**Child**

```
<Range disabled={this.props.disabled}
          values={this.state.values}
          step={STEP}
          min={MIN}
          max={MAX}
          onChange={(values) => {
            this.setState({ values });}}
```

**Parent**

```
<Slider textAlign={"start"} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try**

```
<Range disabled={this.props.disabled}
          values={this.state.values}
          step={STEP}
          min={MIN}
          max={MAX}
          onChange={(values) => {
            this.setState({ values });
this.props.onValueChange(values);

}}

<Slider textAlign={"start"} onValueChange = {(values) => newFunctionHere(values)}  />
```